# Laravel upload file limit validation

Tags: php, laravel

How to set laravel upload file limit to 3 in valdation. If they upload more than that show validation error. `max` keyword is reserved to file size.

How to do for number of files and limit it to 3?

```php
'image' => 'required',
'image.*' => 'nullable|image|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png|dimensions:width=1920,height=1080|max:2048'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use size instead of max.

'image.*' => 'nullable|image|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png|dimensions:width=1920,height=1080|size:2048'

Answer (score -1):

Request arguments with `array` type values can be validated with `max` or `min` to limit length.

```
'image' => ['required', 'max:3'],
```